# Ask user to signup/login when someone connects to my WiFi network

Tags: wifi

I want that when somebody connects to my WiFi network, the user should be redirected to a website, where he either needs to sign up or login(if already registered). He can only use the WiFi after successful login.

I see such networks in most of the restaurants and hotels, does any one know how to create one like that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a [captive portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal). There are many free and open source versions (such as WifiDog, NoCatAuth, CoovaChilli) as well as some for-pay versions (Antamedia Hotspot, FirstSpot). You can also get some equipment (especially wireless LAN controllers) that have built-in captive portals (Netgear, Aruba, Cisco). You can also find instructions online for designing and building your own custom portal like [this page](http://www.andybev.com/index.php/Using_iptables_and_PHP_to_create_a_captive_portal).